# Place images directly under each other (DIV/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to move the images up together.

Please see attached screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

The row of pictures below is meant to move up (1, 2, 3, 4 etc), so that the layout displays correctly - at the moment it's stuck below the highest image leaving white space.

Link to image:
[image]

I am using the below HTML and CSS codes:

```css
div.content-wrapper {
 margin: auto; 
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
  display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:center;
 }
  

 table {border-collapse: collapse;
  padding:0; margin:0;
 border-spacing: 0;}

 td {border-collapse: collapse;
  padding:0; margin:0;
 border-spacing: 0;
 vertical-align: text-top;
}

 td img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 vertical-align: text-top;

 }

 tr {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
 vertical-align: text-top;
}

 img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 


</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div  id="content-wrapper" align="center">
 <div class="row">
   <img src="images/imosec_01.gif" width="1017" height="343 alt="">
 </div>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/imosec_02.gif" width="197" height="119"></td>
<td><img src="images/imosec_03.gif" width="128" height="138"></td>
<td><img src="images/imosec_04.gif" width="51"></td>
<td><img src="images/imosec_05.gif" width="134" height="159"></td>
<td><img src="images/imosec_06.gif" width="47"></td>
<td><img src="images/imosec_07.gif" width="149" height="201"></td>
<td><img src="images/imosec_08.gif" width="26"></td>
<td><img src="images/imosec_09.gif" width="132" height="138"></td>
<td><img src="images/imosec_10.gif" width="153" height="138"></td>
<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="119" alt=""></td>

</tr>


<tr>
<td><img src="images/imosec_11.gif" width="50"></td>
<td><img src="images/imosec_12.gif" width="147" height="128"/></td>
<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="19" alt=""></td>
</tr>


</div>

</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of width and height are those? No units?

Comment: Keeping data in distinct rows is one of the basic features of a table - but having content from lower rows automatically move up, should there still be “space left” in the previous row, absolutely _isn’t_. The first thing you want to do here is get rid of the table. Tables should not be used as layout tool to begin with, and here in this instance they make what you want rather impossible right away.

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke On a <img> the default height and width that your browser read is on **pixels**. So <img src="#" height="12" width="12" alt=""> is the same as  <img src="#" height="12px" width="12px" alt="">. But you're right it's better to make explicit units on your tag.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear but one thing is sure : you **missed a quote mark** at the end of the image tag after the height :

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="images/imosec_01.gif" width="1017" height="343" alt="">
</div>
```

**EDIT** : You close the `</div>` tag before closing your `</table>` tag. That isn't correct. You should respect the order :

```
<div>
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

To avoid this kind of problem, always close a tag just after you open it (and write the content between those tags).

Have you also tried to use div instead of table ? 
You can also have a look at Bootstrap library that is helpful to make a proper html / css code and it is easy to use : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/